# fixing this code to get data from google voice

Tags: javascript, google-api

So I've posted this on reddit and here I am, sorry for the copy paste

---

Edit:

So I've removed the original post from codinghelp subreddit since someone told me it is against the rules

and it seems like the problem is in getting the URL which will trigger the query, according to the files in developer tools it seems like google uses java script, angular and apache 2.0.

__________________________________________

Hello

So I was interested in getting a list of available google voice numbers, did some googling and found this code,

https://github.com/fulldecent/google-voice-numbers/blob/master/1.%20Get%20all%20available%20numbers.md

So here's the thing, I think google has changed their authentication cookies, but not sure, BUT I'm pretty sure they changed their API and the code doesn't run, for example:

```
 mkdir ~/Desktop/GOOGLEVOICE; cd ~/Desktop/GOOGLEVOICE URL="https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/setup/searchnew/" HEADER="PASTE HERE"
```

The header is supposed to be the authentication cookies which I think they changed

The link to get to the choose/search new URL is now this

```
 https://voice.google.com/u/0/signup
```

I've tried to change these values but didn't work.

Also I can't get into on what the part after URL means here, I think he is pinging an area code to check if the code works

The "?ac=..." isn't valid anymore and I can't get the new url

```
curl -H $HEADER "${URL}?ac=484&q=484&start=0&country=US"
```

Here's a PHP code developed by someone on this guy's blog

https://privacylog.blogspot.com/2009/08/full-google-hack.html

Here it is

​

```
Here's a PHP script I made derived from this post. I'm sharing this as my way of saying thank you.

to run the script below you need to supply the ac and s parameters like so

http://localhost/gv.php?ac=121$s=0
s should be looped and incremented by 5 each time since google will give you 5 numbers each page.

------------
'GOOGLE',
'Email' => 'username@gmail.com',
'Passwd' => 'password',
'source'=>'PHI-cUrl-Example',
'service'=>'grandcentral'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$msg = curl_exec($ch);

$cookies = split("\n",$msg);
//print_r($cookies);

$ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com/voice/b/0/setup/searchnew/?ac=".$_GET['ac']."&start=". $_GET['s']);

$header[] = 'Authorization: GoogleLogin ' . $cookies[2];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$msg = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$arr_data = json_decode($msg);
echo "matches found = " . $arr_data->JSON->num_matches . "
";
foreach($arr_data->JSON->vanity_info as $numbers=>$whatever){
echo $numbers . "
";
}

?>
```

I can see that you enter the email and password and it does the heavy lifting, but they changed the API (been so many years) so I think the links/arguments are broken

I'm not a programmer and barely know the basics so I was looking for some help
Tried contacting the developer but he hasn't replied since last week, and I think this is as far as my googling skills can go.

​

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what your *question* is, please take the [tour], read [ask] and [edit] this question to meet the requirements.

Comment: I found the code online after researching but google have changed their API/Google voice layout and now it isn't working, was checking if someone knows how to fix it.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:git]?

Comment: The code is applied in git bash